# Uri encoding, file download doesn't work with , and whitespace

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, web, urlencode

I have an asp.net webpage that allows downloading files.

When i had the problem of downloading a file with `whitespace(Test 1 4 3.txt)` it will turn the file into: `Test+1+4+3.txt`

I used:

```
_Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(_fileName, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8));
```

And it solved the issue.

Now i have a new issue:
When a file contains `,` it changes it into `%2c` and i the UrlEncode doesn't fix it.
i Tried using:

```
_Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(_fileName));
```

But it's the old setting and it doesn't support whitespace.

What can i do to solve such a case?
Should i use regex / switch?

This is my function:

```
 public static bool ResponseFile(HttpRequest _Request, HttpResponse _Response, string _fileName, string _fullPath, long _speed = 1024000)
    {
        try
        {
            FileStream myFile = new FileStream(_fullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(myFile);
            try
            {
                _Response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
                _Response.Buffer = false;
                long fileLength = myFile.Length;
                long startBytes = 0;

                int pack = 10240; //10K bytes
                int sleep = (int)Math.Floor((double)(1000 * pack / _speed)) + 1;
                if (_Request.Headers["Range"] != null)
                {
                    _Response.StatusCode = 206;
                    string[] range = _Request.Headers["Range"].Split(new char[] { '=', '-' });
                    startBytes = Convert.ToInt64(range[1]);
                }
                _Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", (fileLength - startBytes).ToString());
                if (startBytes != 0)
                {
                    _Response.AddHeader("Content-Range", string.Format(" bytes {0}-{1}/{2}", startBytes, fileLength - 1, fileLength));
                }
                _Response.AddHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                _Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

                //Old didn't work with both + and ,
                //_Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(_fileName, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8));
                _Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(_fileName));

                br.BaseStream.Seek(startBytes, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                int maxCount = (int)Math.Floor((double)((fileLength - startBytes) / pack)) + 1;

                for (int i = 0; i < maxCount; i++)
                {
                    if (_Response.IsClientConnected)
                    {
                        _Response.BinaryWrite(br.ReadBytes(pack));
                        Thread.Sleep(sleep);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        i = maxCount;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
            finally
            {
                br.Close();
                myFile.Close();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved it:
_Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + _fileName + "\"");